# A sequence with a special mediant property

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've noticed that the sequence   1/1,   2/3,   1/2,   2/5,   1/3,   2/7,   1/4,   2/9, ... has the property that each entry is the mediant of two entries symmetrically disposed about it. How should I go about finding whether it is unique in this respect? I've tried a vector representation, where the magnitude of the mediant appears as a gradient, but I can't get a feel for the relevant parameters.

Comment: Can you find a pattern? EG Extrapolate from 1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4  ... and 2/3, 2/5, 2/7, 2/9, ....  Hint: With the right view, the answer is immediate.

Comment: Unique? What about $1/1,\,1/2,\,1/3,\,1/4...$?

Comment: Yes, Ivan, I realised that I could take any sequence with unit numerator and denominators in arithmetic progression, and indeed any sequence derived from one such by successive interpolation of mediants. Thanks, Calvin, the penny hasn't dropped yet but give me time.

Comment: I've overgeneralised: it doesn't work after the first set of interpolations.

Comment: I've managed to identify 4 cases: (A1) numerator 1, denominators in A.P., (A2) same with mediants interpolated, (B1) numerator 2, denominators in A.P. with odd first term, even common difference, (B2) same with mediants interpolated. But, Calvin, you've spotted a simpler pattern?

Comment: I can summarise those 4 cases as my original sequence where we take every k th term, and k is at least 1. Unfortunately that does not include the trivial case 1/1, 1/1, 1/1, ... . More help, please.

Comment: Disregard: I've just read Stan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_i$ and $b_i$ are two arithmetic progressions then the sequence
$$\frac{sa_1}{sb_1},\frac{ta_2}{tb_2},\frac{sa_3}{sb_3},\frac{ta_4}{tb_4},\frac{sa_5}{sb_5}, ...$$ has the required property.

Example:

Your original sequence is based upon $2,2,2,...$ and $2,3,4,...$ with $s=\frac{1}{2}, t=1$.